# How do you face decoding issues?

Tags: tools, character-encoding

For what I understand, given a sequence of bytes without any further information, it's not generally possible to understand which encoding we are talking about. Of course we can guess (e.g. perl's `Encode::Guess` and similar tools), but sometimes this is just not feasible.

In my case, I've got a byte array which is `\xe2\x80\xa1`, and I can guess from the context (as a human) that it should correspond either to a `à` character (`\xc3\xa0` in *UTF-8*) or to a `á` (`\xc3\xa1` in *UTF-8*). It comes from an xml which declares *iso8859-1* in the header, and is produced by a third party tool, which is clearly broken, but I have to deal with it. As you can guess the decoding fails, and no luck with `Encode::Guess`.

How would you face this kind of problem? I know there's no silver bullet, but is there a tool which outstands the others?

Comment: If the tool claims to generate iso latin-1 outout, and manifestly doesn't, then there is by definition something wrong with it and must be fixed. What other possibility could there be?

Comment: @KilianFoth, exactly, I totally agree with you. Sometimes however you don't have control on it. Let me fix the question btw...

Comment: Never trust the content-type in the XML file.

Comment: To be honest, I have never in my life received an Ã that was actually *supposed* an Ã. It was *always* a German umlaut encoded in UTF8 read by someone expecting Latin1. So in practice, you're pretty safe assuming that anything with \xc3 in it is actually UTF-8 text. (But don't tell anyone I said that, please.)

Comment: Check out this SO question and its answers: **[Correcting the XML encoding](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4674835/439793)**. It is about a Python program but the general idea should be applicable to any language.

Comment: Pssst... @Snowman, you should put that as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML encoding can be tricky, because some XML generators might hard-code a generic content type such as ISO-8859-1 even if the document contains e.g. UTF-8. Part of the reason is most text is ASCII, and valid (7-bit) ASCII is also valid as most other encodings. Developers might not understand character encoding or might not care (works with *my* test data!).

One general approach is to attempt to decode the XML using the provided content-type. As with HTML, this is located near the top of the document and no non-ASCII characters should be between the start of the document and this encoding (except for byte order marks which implicitly provide a content-type).

If this encoding fails, then try with one or more predefined content-types. Good candidates are UTF-8, UTF-16, and ISO-8859-1. Plain old (7-bit) ASCII also decodes fine as UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1 so that is implied here as well.

Please note that depending on the language and XML implementation you may be able to "plow through" errors or not: it is best to have it fail fast on errors so you know to try another encoding.

### See Also

- [Correcting the XML encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4674835/439793)
- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: Aha! That absolute minimum is the one in perlunitut, isn't it? :D